# What is the best data model design for Addresses in database

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, entity-relationship

What is the best data model design for saving Addresses in a database, one design is as follows:

1. Table `Countries`
2. Table `Provinces` (fk to `Countries`)
3. Table `Cities` (fk to `Provinces`)
4. Table `Addresses` (fk to `Cities`), Main street column
5. Table `Customer`
6. Table `CustomerAddresses` (fk to `Customer` and fk to `Addresses`)

But the problem of this design is that addresses of some customers have not city and just country is specified, or for one customer city is specified but province and country is not specified and ...

What is the best design for this issue?

Comment: As you consider this problem, think about what you'll need to do with this data.  What will the outward-facing UI provide?  What about the internal UI?  Will you need to run these addresses through NCOA (or a similar database for whatever country is at issue)?  Depending on how clean you set it up now, and how clean the data is, that can affect costs and discounts for mass mailings.  In short, your schema should be built around the expected future uses.  (I'd consider adding a postcode field, though; for the US, zip+4 can made a difference in discounts.)

Comment: A nice read on the subject: https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/

Answer (score 0):

```
    1- Table Countries
    2- Table Provinces (fk to countries)
    3- Table cities  (fk to Provinces)
    4- Table Addresses (fk to cities,fk to Countries,FK to Provinces,FK to Customers)
    5- Table Customer
```

Now `Addresses` Table will be like this:

```
{PK_ID,Customer_ID,Country_ID,Province_ID,City_ID,StreetAddress}
```

In this way you can easily save addresses of customers into `Addresses` table

Comment: I think that it is not so normalize.

Comment: it is. You can verify